# notepad++ extension for new files

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ is nice utility which I use everyday. I often use it to copy code snippets temporarily which I have no intention to save. I usually create a new tab to do this. The problem that I have is this- new tab is created as "new xx" and since there is no file extension, syntax highlighting does not work. Is there a  fix so that I can get syntax highlighting without saving it?

Thanks,
GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the `Language` menu and choose the language you want to set syntax highlighting for your unsaved file.